# Redirecting Prior To Page Display (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

Got an AngularJS app set up, where some views require you to be logged in. Other views are publicly available. Ideally, the user would be redirected to the login page (which is currently outside the scope of the app) before any of the view is displayed.

Since it has to redirect depending on the hash-value, this can't be done back-end. I have the redirecting working alright within the js, although there is the issue that using `$window.location.href` does not seem to prevent the javascript from running. So you still get that quick flash of what was on the page.

Note, all info is validated back-end as well, so the user can't see anything they're not meant to. It's just a matter of UX. Would prefer not have the page quickly flash before redirecting.

Is there any way to tell the browser to stop executing after `$window.location.href`?

**EDIT:**

While not an optimal solution, I've decided to have the `<body>` hidden by default. Then I use an if-else to either redirect or show the body.

I'm still interested, if anyone can think of a better solution?

Comment: While not an optimal solution, I've decided to have the `<body>` hidden by default. Then I use an if-else to either redirect or show the body.